# How do you specify a custom location for crossdomain.xml in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, crossdomain.xml

We are hosting the swf assets on a media hosting server and can't get a file to the root, anyone know what the code looks like to specify a custom location for crossdomain.xml? Sample code if you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but I found the code so I thought I'd post here to add to the reference value of this question:

> pulled from: http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=117
>
> The problem with setting up a crossdomain.xml file on the SSL server is that I don’t have access to the server. It’s just pointing to a virtual root on my server and I don’t have access to the SSL server’s web root.
>
> flash.system.Security.loadPolicyFile("{Url to my crossdomain.xml file on the SSL virtual root}");
>
> With these changes in place, I’m able to easily integrate Google Accounts with my Flash app.

Comment: Just something that you might want to take note of the "opt-in meta policies" security changes that comes Flash 9 and higher version players. You might want to refer to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9-10_security.html

Comment: If you accept the answer, this won't show up as "unanswered".